# android webview display is delayed

Tags: android, webview

I got an `Acivity` holding a `WebView` displayed on the screen right when it get turned on.  The `WebView` itself is already loaded before. I expect the `WebView` to be displayed with the rest of the `Activity`, but instead it is delayed by half a second, so I got a big hole in my layout for this half second.

This happen only the first time the view is displayed after been created.

I do not want the activity to be visible while the `WebView` isn't, but I cannot find anything telling me when the `WebView` is avalaible. I tried with `getDrawingRect` and such, but their values are still been changed before the `WebView` is visible.

Is it possible to know exactly when a `WebView` is displayed, or even to erase that delay?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `onPageFinished` lest you know then the `WebView` is completely loaded, untill then display a progress bar and in `onPageFinished` let your complete layout visible

Comment: The page is already loaded while the screen is off. I use a wakelock that is released precisly when onPageFinished is called.